# how to run some code whenever function from particular class is called in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I made a simple console application in java, it is about bank, we can create accounts, then deposit money and do other transaction withing account, till now it is just in memory application, now I want to store account data and transaction logs in pgsql db.

I made a new DAO file, so i can import function in account DAO and transaction DAO.

What I want is to run this code before any database functions are called

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/javaBank", "postgres", "puru2000");
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

and this after the the function

```
conn.close();
```

Should I just write this code in starting and ending of every function or is there is any efficient method to do this.

Here is my project repo if u need ref.`https://github.com/dexterpuru/java-banking`

Comment: Do you really want to open a connection each time you call a method? In this case the most sensible way would be to keep the connection while the program is running.

Comment: You don't need conn.close() if you use try-with-resources. The first two lines can be reduced in a static method call: MyConnections.getConnection();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of application, I suggest you to use spring and hibernate, if you don't want to use it, then you should not open connection in every method. Open connection globally and set `conn.setAutoCommit(true);` and after each method call some command is executed and automatically commited. Commonly opening and closing connection can make problems if methods are called often.

Comment: what will happen if i don't close my connection, for example i exit the program in between.

Comment: Connection will close automatically when you exit program